# using a named set in a calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a calculated field (getting a count) and a named set (defines a key) which I want to use in a new calculated member and return the count based on when the key is defined in that set.

So far i have tried this:

`([Measures].[Person ID Distinct Count], [SET])` and

`([Measures].[Person ID Distinct Count], {[SET]})`

Just on a side note, I for this discount count in 2 steps:

I first did a count on the table using `new measure...` option from `cube structure` pane, then used it in a calculation to define the year of count i want. And now I am here. My mdx above didn't work but however in the browser i can pull the count (where its filtered by year) and use the set as a slice and it works fine. But I want this defined in a calculation.

Comment: How about `AGGREGATE([SET], [Measures].[Person ID Distinct Count])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This signifies a tuple `(....)`

A tuple is made up of members - so a set cannot be used as an argument.

You need to aggregate your set separately to create a member:

```
Aggregate([SET])
```

The memeber can then be used in the tuple you mention:

```
([Measures].[Person ID Distinct Count], [SomeDim].[SomeHierarchy].[All].[AggregatedSET])
```

Comment: @Faiz did this help you?